# How can I deal with this singularity

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, singularity

I would like to compute numerically the definite integral below using the Simpson rule:

$$\int\limits_0^1 \ln (x) \ln (1-x)\ dx$$

But I have difficulty trying to remove the singularity in this integral.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The limits of the integrand at the endpoints are both zero. Once you replace those two points, you have a typical bounded continuous function on the unit interval.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a singularity with natural log, then your solution is imaginary. The indefinite integral of $\ln(x)\ln(x-1)$ is $$x((\ln(x-1)-1)\ln(x)-\ln(x-1)+2)+\ln(x-1)+ Li_2 (1-x)+C$$Using integral-calculator.com . Li_2 is $$\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{x^k}{k^2}$$ Now note that the natural log of -1 is $\pi i$, so our final answer is $$\pi i -2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ Hope this helps :)